# Is it safe to use Parse.Object.attributes?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Is it safe to use the object.attributes property of a Parse.Object when reading and writing?

I know the way it says in the docs to use a Parse.Object is via

```
object.set("myprop",0)
```

and

```
object.get("myprop")
```

but can I just do

```
object.attributes.myprop = 0
```

and

```
var x = object.attributes.myprop;
```

will that work when calling object.save()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Parse JavaScript SDK is based on Backbonejs, Parse.Object shares a lot with [Backbone.Model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set)

In this scenario, instead of just changing the value of the property, 'set' changes the model's **state** which may affect other operations, for example, the dirty checking, and so the model would overlook the changes and therefore fail to update.

[Backbone.Model attributes](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code you gave and it does not work. You do have to use the get and set functions on an object. Why are you against using them?

**Works:**

```
object.set("myprop",0);
object.get("myprop");
```

**Doesn't Work:**

```
object.attributes.myprop = 0;
object.attributes.myprop;
```